# Ошибка в jLabel.setText

Tags: java, netbeans

Распишу все действия последовательно.

1. Создаю проект Java в NetBeans (8.1)
2. Добавляю библиотеку `Jsoup` ( а именно Jar файлы скачанные с официального сайта)
3. Создаю `Jframe` и кидаю `jLabel1` (компонент)

```js
package pkgclass;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;


public class Class {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bcs-express.ru/kotirovki-i-grafiki/gazp").get();
        String a = doc.select(".emet_index").text();
        jLabel1.setText(a);


    }

}
```

Пожалуйста скажите почему ругается на `jlabel`?

Скрины прилагаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше  не столько прилагать скрины, сколько выкладывать сам код.

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jLabel1`, это поле класса `JFrame`, которое к тому же создаётся в NetBeans изначально закрытым (`private`). Из класса `Class1` к нему нельзя обратиться напрямую.

Для того чтобы задать текст пишите в классе `JFrame` сеттер для данного свойства `jLabel1` и работайте с ним.

```
public void setJLabel1Text(String s)
    {
        jLabel1.setText(s);
    }
```

Примерно как-то так.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bcs-express.ru/kctircvki-i-grafrki/cazp").get();
String a = doc.select(".emet_index").text();
JFrame jFrm= new JFrame();
jFrm.setJLabel1Text(a);
```

Надеюсь, принцип понятен...

Comment: То есть я делаю все в классе Jframe? я правильно понял? .

Comment: При запуске проекта вывоходит фрейм и в нем Jlabel1  ну и все. Что делать?

Comment: Какой класс в приложении является главным (`Class1` или `JFrame`)?

Comment: Class является главным

Comment: Если `Class1` - действительно главный, то приведённый в ответе принцип должен 100% сработать. Видимо что-то сделали не так. Что именно? Так сказать не могу. Нужно видеть Ваш код. Как Вы реализовали принцип из ответа. Тогда можно будет конкретно подсказать. К слову, то что `Class1` главный Вы узнали из свойств проекта?

Comment: Прощу прощения главным классом является Frame. Через свойства почему то доступен только Frame

Comment: То есть в ветке "Свойства"->"Выполнение"->"Главный класс" установлено `JFrame`? И, как я полагаю, Ваш код выложен [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476146/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-jsoup-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-jframe)?

Comment: Да. все верно. Да но там как вы и сказали первая часть кода размещена в классе Frame, а часть вывода в лейбл в Class

Comment: Дело в том, что главный класс - это класс, метод `main` которого используется в качестве точки входа в программу (т.е., другими словами, для её запуска). Если главный класс - `JFrame`, а Вы разметили код работы с библиотекой и всего остального в методе 'main' класса 'Class1', то этот метод `main` будет просто проигнорирован. Либо указывайте в свойствах (см.предыдущий мой комментарий) `Class1` в качестве главного. Либо переносите всё в `JFrame`.

Comment: все перенес в Frame  опять также при запуске только jLabel1. Извините а можно ли как то связаться с вами. Если  вы не заняты и если готовы уделить немного  времени мне. к примеру скайп или вотс, телеграм, вк. В любом случае спасибо за детальное объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

У вас переменная `jLabel1` не объявлена. А когда вы её объявите не забудьте её инициализировать. В данный момент IDE видит лишь бесммысленный набор символов, коий не может связать с чем-либо, в т.ч. с к-л виджетом, в коий можно поместить текст, о чём вам и сообщает.

Comment: Юрий, не сочтите за наглость. Можете пример привезти?

Comment: @Showmeyoupower, я с этой технологией не знаком, см. ответ Streletz